# Trying to compile Qt with VS2010 sp1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm trying to compile Qt with VS2010sp1 compiler and I went successfully through configure step. Next step when I have to run nmake, after a while of working gives me following error:

fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch;

What to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

IFAIK that's usually a bad VS install, or mixing PDBs from an earlier install with an updated version.

Try reinstalling VS, or the service pack

Comment: and how could I've mixed them, if I didn't do anything?

Comment: If this is a new build then it's probably a bad VS install, if you are continuing a build from before an upgrade delete all the PDBs